# 3 images next to each other

Tags: android, image

I got in my android app,  3images put like this.
first image and second image below each other, and third image next to them.The problem I have is i get from server side different images, and different sizes. How can I organize them, so that they look nicely on screen.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot edited as some wanted to take a look:
1 and 2 images on left, 3rd on side.

https://s30.postimg.org/bs6m2vtfl/Screen_Shot_2017_02_07_at_4_55_25_PM.png

Comment: can you share some screen  shot?

Comment: how different in size they can be? do always want to show 3 of them on the whole screen?  You cant try using layout_weight  and match_parent to try and organize them (this will stretch/shring the images)

Comment: lets assume three pictures will always be 800*1200 or 1200 *800

Comment: Consider accepting answer if helped..!!!

Comment: nthg much helped,  because at end of day all solutions were same like ones i thought. at end of day i agreed with user to give me all images square. and i simply divided the 2 sides to 1  - 2 ratio. thanks for all for the answers.

Comment: that way, i avoided stretching of image or quality losing.

Answer (score 1):

As your question not clear about the layout and responsive design. The answer as per your added image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_spare_request"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bob"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bob"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bob"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

you can try simple layout, Layout nesting is not really a good approach you should use like this

```
<LinearLayout android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: he wants 3rd image next to them, not under them

Comment: He is trying the same it he wants next to them he needs to set  android:orientation="vertical" that will solve his problem.

Comment: edited the question with screenshot, to make it more clear.